# Is there a way to call a class function from another class directly without an instance of it in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have an application that I have taking a picture, and then it is supposed to send the data from the picture to another activity using an intent.

I am trying to call the intent inside the `jpegCallback`, but the problem is I also need to release the camera through the preview class before calling the intent. However, I can not get to the original preview object from inside the callback, so I need a way to call `MainActivity.doPictureResults()` from inside the callback. Or I need a way to have a listener that fires after all of the picture callbacks are done.

Here is my `MainActivity` class which holds an instance of `Preview` class in the `mPreview` variable. The `jpegCallback` is at the bottom, and I want to call the `doPictureResults` from inside that, or setup another callback for after that function is done.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Preview mPreview;
    Camera mCamera;
    int numberOfCameras;
    int cameraCurrentlyLocked;

    //The first rear facing camera
    int defaultCameraId;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param savedInstanceState 
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Hide the window title.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //Create a RelativeLayout container that will hold a SurfaceView,
        //and set it as the content of our activity.
        this.mPreview = new Preview(this);
        setContentView(this.mPreview);

        //Find the total number of cameras available
        this.numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        //Find the ID of the default camera
        CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
        for(int i = 0; i < this.numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if(cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                this.defaultCameraId = i;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();

        //Open the default i.e. the first rear facing camera.
        this.mCamera = Camera.open();
        this.cameraCurrentlyLocked = this.defaultCameraId;
        this.mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();

        //Because the Camera object is a shared resource, it's very
        //Important to release it when the activity is paused.
        this.mPreview.releaseCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Inflate our menu which can gather user input for switching camera
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.camera_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.switchCam:
                //Check for availability of multiple cameras
                if(this.numberOfCameras == 1) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage(this.getString(R.string.camera_alert)).setNeutralButton("Close", null);
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                    return true;
                }

                //OK, we have multiple cameras.
                //Release this camera -> cameraCurrentlyLocked
                this.mPreview.releaseCamera();

                //Acquire the next camera and request Preview to reconfigure parameters.
                this.mCamera = Camera.open((this.cameraCurrentlyLocked + 1) % this.numberOfCameras);
                this.cameraCurrentlyLocked = (this.cameraCurrentlyLocked + 1) % this.numberOfCameras;
                this.mPreview.switchCamera(mCamera);

                //Start the preview
                this.mCamera.startPreview();
                return true;

            case R.id.takePicture:
                this.mCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void doPictureResults(byte[] data) {
        this.mPreview.releaseCamera();

        //Release the camera and send the results of the image to the GetResults view
        Intent resultsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageProcessorActivity.class);
        resultsIntent.putExtra("image_data", data);
        startActivity(resultsIntent);
    }

    /**
     * Handles data for jpeg picture when the picture is taken
     */
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() { 
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera mCamera) {Log.e(TAG, "jpegCallback");
            String baseExternalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            String fileName = String.format("Assist/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                //Create the directory if needed
                File assistDirectory = new File(baseExternalDir + File.separator + "Assist");
                assistDirectory.mkdirs();

                // Write to SD Card
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(baseExternalDir + File.separator + fileName);
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by PictureCallback()", e);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by PictureCallback()", e);
            } 

            //This is the type of thing I WANT to do....but its not possible.
            MainActivity.doPictureResults();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One options would be to create a PictureCallback implementation that saved the information was required in `doPictureResults`. It's not clear if `doPictureResults` will be called anywhere else; if it's not, this is clean and isolates the functionality.

Another would be to have the activity itself implement `PictureCallback` so you have direct access to all the member variables without having to do any work at all. This allows `doPictureResults` to be called from other places.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements PictureCallback {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            ....
            case R.id.takePicture:
                this.mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    ...
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera mCamera) {
        Log.d(TAG, "jpegCallback");
        String baseExternalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
        ...
        doPictureResults();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! That second option is what I am looking for, but I do not know how to put the PictureCallback inside the MainActivity? If you could please show me that, it would solve my problem. I figured there was a way but I am very new to this programming and the only examples I have seen work the way this one does.

Comment: Okay awesome, so in java can I implement as many interfaces as I want like this? So could i also implement the ShutterCallback?

Comment: @Metropolis Classes may implement as many interfaces as they want.

Comment: cool, thats what I thought but just wanted to be sure. One last thing, if I need 3 PictureCallbacks, how can I differentiate them in the same class? Could you please add that to your code on the takePicture(this, this, this). Sorry for all the questions, just want to make sure I am understanding this stuff.

Comment: @Metropolis You mean three versions of `onPictureTaken`? You can't; you can only have one `onPictureTaken` method. Or three versions of `doPictureResults`? Then you'd need to create a `PictureCallback` implementation that has enough information to differentiate between conditions and call the correct method. In either case, the only prerequisite is that *something* needs to know enough to decide what to call.

Comment: i meant 3 callbacks for raw, postview, and jpeg callbacks. They are all the same type, so I was wondering how to do all of those in the same class this way.

Answer (score 0):

The only methods you can call on a class without an instance are static methods, but I don't know if that will do what you want here.

Comment: I thought static methods may be a possiblity....But I do not want the instance I have to be static, so that wont work. What about some sort of a callback? Can I create a callback that fires after that function is over? Or can I setup the jpegCallback to be a part of my MainActivity class? Im very new to java/android so sorry for the newbie questions.